# How to solve circular reference in json serializer caused by circular reference error

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am developing a legacy system. Now I need to change the data to Json, but stuck in circular reference problem. I have searched answers, like use [jackson reference](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences)

The code as follows:

```
public abstract class OWLNode {
// parent-child links
@JsonBackReference protected List<OWLNode> superNodes;
@JsonBackReference  protected List<OWLNode> children;
protected String label;
protected HierarchyElement element;
protected static OWLNode[] LEAF_NODE = new OWLNode[0];
}
```

The error is:

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: circular reference error
> Offending field: children
> ```

Comment: Based on the reference you linked, I think you should use `@JsonManagedReference` annotation for `children` field

Comment: it also reports the same error.